'mit wessem' oder 'mit wessen'
Welche Frage ist richtig?
Mit wessem Auto seid ihr gefahren?

oder
Mit wessen Auto seid ihr gefahren?

Ich vermüte die erste aber bin nicht sicher; mit braucht Dativ, oder?

Das Wort "wessem" existiert nicht - Es scheint ein Versuch zu sein, gleichzeitig den Genitiv und den Dativ zu verwenden, das funktioniert aber nicht.
Damit du fragen kannst, wem das Auto gehört, musst du den Genitiv von "wer" verwenden, und das ist "wessen". "Mit" verlangt zwar den Dativ, aber nicht vom Fragepronomen, sondern nur vom "Auto", dem man das hier leider nicht ansieht.
